# Using regex formulas in SQL Server SSMS IDE

Tags: regex, replace, ssms

I have the following query after Script table as INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO [DWH].[DimSharedDimensionEmployee]
       ([EmployeeId]
       ,[AdminFileId]
       ,[ManagerId]
       ,[EmployeeLastname]
       ,[EmployeeFirstname]
       ,[ManagerFirstname]
       ,[ManagerLastname]
       ,[EmployeeEmail]
       ,[ManagerEmail]
       ,[EmployeeTrigram]
       ,[ManagerTrigram]
       ,[MainFunction]
       ,[EmployeeStatus]
       ,[EmployeeType]
       ,[Gender]
       ,[Department]
       ,[Governance]
       ,[IsWantedBack]
       ,[IsPhysicallyInOffice]
       ,[ContractType]
       ,[BillingTo]
       ,[WorkingFor]
       ,[HostedBy]
       ,[EmployedBy]
       ,[OfficeExtension]
       ,[Office]
       ,[FirstEntryDate]
       ,[EntryDate]
       ,[ExitDate]
       ,[PreferredLanguage]
       ,[BirthDate]
       ,[BirthPlace]
       ,[Nationnalities]
       ,[RecentDiploma]
       ,[RecentSchool]
       ,[RDYearObtained]
       ,[MaritalSituation]
       ,[CurrentRecord]
       ,[BI_StartDate]
       ,[BI_EndDate])
 VALUES
       (<EmployeeId, int,>
       ,<AdminFileId, int,>
       ,<ManagerId, int,>
       ,<EmployeeLastname, nvarchar(50),>
       ,<EmployeeFirstname, nvarchar(50),>
       ,<ManagerFirstname, nvarchar(50),>
       ,<ManagerLastname, nvarchar(50),>
       ,<EmployeeEmail, nvarchar(100),>
       ,<ManagerEmail, nvarchar(100),>
       ,<EmployeeTrigram, nvarchar(5),>
       ,<ManagerTrigram, nvarchar(5),>
       ,<MainFunction, nvarchar(1024),>
       ,<EmployeeStatus, nvarchar(255),>
       ,<EmployeeType, nvarchar(255),>
       ,<Gender, nvarchar(20),>
       ,<Department, nvarchar(1024),>
       ,<Governance, nvarchar(1024),>
       ,<IsWantedBack, bit,>
       ,<IsPhysicallyInOffice, bit,>
       ,<ContractType, nvarchar(255),>
       ,<BillingTo, nvarchar(50),>
       ,<WorkingFor, nvarchar(50),>
       ,<HostedBy, nvarchar(50),>
       ,<EmployedBy, nvarchar(50),>
       ,<OfficeExtension, nvarchar(max),>
       ,<Office, nvarchar(max),>
       ,<FirstEntryDate, datetime2(7),>
       ,<EntryDate, datetime2(7),>
       ,<ExitDate, datetime2(7),>
       ,<PreferredLanguage, varchar(128),>
       ,<BirthDate, datetime2(7),>
       ,<BirthPlace, nvarchar(max),>
       ,<Nationnalities, nvarchar(max),>
       ,<RecentDiploma, nvarchar(max),>
       ,<RecentSchool, nvarchar(256),>
       ,<RDYearObtained, int,>
       ,<MaritalSituation, varchar(25),>
       ,<CurrentRecord, bit,>
       ,<BI_StartDate, datetime2(7),>
       ,<BI_EndDate, datetime2(7),>)
```

I copy and paste it in SSMS and want to replace the values by ? in order to use it in SSIS. I want to use a regex formula here :

[image]

Comment: Great, so what's stopping you? You have the `.*` button (which indicates to use Regular Expressions) turned on; I don't see what what the problem is.

Comment: @Larnu I tried this one but in vain :  <[^a-z0-9]>

Comment: Show what your attempts were in your question, along with what the expected result is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If* I understand your question correctly, and you want to replace the string enclosed in `<` and `>` with a `?`, then you simply need the REGEX `(<.*>)` in the find box, and `?` in the replace box, and the `.*` button enabled for Regular Expressions.
[image]